# Unable to connect to AIX(Unix) box with SSH.NET Library - Error : Value cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, ssh, putty, aix

I am trying to connect to an **AIX** box and execute some commands using **`SSH.NET`** library.
The following is the code snipplet

```
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new(ConnectionInfo(servername, 22, username, pauth,kauth);
SshClient sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
sshClient.Connect();
SshCommand sshCommand = sshClient.RunCommand("mpstat");
Console.WriteLine(sshCommand.Result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

I get the following **exception message** when I try to connect at the line `sshClient.Connect()`

> {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: data"}

The stack trace is

```
   at Renci.SshNet.KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod.Authenticate(Session session)
   at Renci.SshNet.ConnectionInfo.Authenticate(Session session)
   at Renci.SshNet.Session.Connect()
   at Renci.SshNet.BaseClient.Connect()
```

I am confident that the credentials I pass are valid since I am **able to log-in** using the **`PuTTY`** client with the same credentials. Any ideas?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution after some research. Hope it helps somebody else.

The **keyboard interactive authentication** should be used and **`AuthenticationPrompt`** event should be overridden with the following function

```
void HandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
    {
        if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
        {
            prompt.Response = password;
        }
    }
}
```

The function call code :

```
KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(username);
PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(username, password);

kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);

ConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo(serverName, port, username, pauth, kauth);

sshClient = new SshClient(connectionInfo);
sshClient.Connect();
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encapsulated the whole thing so that it's easier to use. Warning: no try/catch has been implemented yet! The DLL is available here: https://sshnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/120504
Tested with SLES (11.1 64), Debian (6), AIX (5.3, 6.1, 7)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Renci.SshNet;
using Renci.SshNet.Common;

namespace SSH2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            SSH client = new SSH("servername", "username", "password");

            MessageBox.Show(client.command("ls -la /"));
        }

    }

    public class SSH
    {
        string servername;
        int port;
        string username;
        string password;

        SshClient Server = null;


        public SSH(string servername, int port, string username, string password)
        {
            this.servername = servername;
            this.port = port;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;

            this.init();
        }

        public SSH(string servername, string username, string password)
        {
            this.servername = servername;
            this.port = 22;
            this.username = username;
            this.password = password;

            this.init();
        }


        private void init()
        {
            KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod kauth = new KeyboardInteractiveAuthenticationMethod(this.username);
            PasswordAuthenticationMethod pauth = new PasswordAuthenticationMethod(this.username, this.password);

            kauth.AuthenticationPrompt += new EventHandler<AuthenticationPromptEventArgs>(HandleKeyEvent);

            this.Server = new SshClient(new ConnectionInfo(this.servername, this.port, this.username, pauth, kauth));
        }


        void HandleKeyEvent(Object sender, AuthenticationPromptEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (AuthenticationPrompt prompt in e.Prompts)
            {
                if (prompt.Request.IndexOf("Password:", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) != -1)
                {
                    prompt.Response = this.password;
                }
            }
        }

        public string command(string cmd)
        {
            this.Server.Connect();

            var output = this.Server.RunCommand(cmd);

            this.Server.Disconnect();

            return output.Result;
        }
    }
}
```